# PHP match_preg_all error (Found sulution)

Tags: php, preg-match-all, hitcounter

I'm currently working on a hit counter that counts whenever a new visitor visits the page, So for each new visitor i create a new .txt file.

The file is stored as "hits/".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].".txt".

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$visits = 0;
$hits = 0;

$fileResource = @fopen("hits/".$remote_addr.".txt","w+");
fwrite($fileResource,
"IP Adress:".$remote_addr."
Timestamp:".time().""
);

$fileResource = @fopen("hits/".$remote_addr.".txt","r");
$fileContent = @fread($fileResource,100000);

preg_match_all("/(.*):(.*)\n/i",$fileContent,$fileMatches);

foreach(glob("hits/*.txt") as $hit){
$hits++;
}
?>
```

So what i am trying to do is:

1. Grab the contents from the file (Done)
2. Format it so it can be displayed in an Admin Panel by getting what's between ":" and \n (Need help)
3. Display it on the Admin Panel

EDIT: i was playing around with the preg_match_all(), And i found the sulution. It was as easy as removing the \n

Comment: can you explain what that code is supposed to do? I can see you open a file and write to it. Then you open the file again in read mode and try to match something from it. Then iterate all the txt files in the directory and increase hits for each file. Then the script ends. That makes no sense to me. How is that going to count the hits at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing \n with \\n in your match expression.
\n is literal character n.
\n is literal \ followed by n.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by replacing \n with \n?

"\" is an escape character, So \n will be converted to a new line

Comment: I've edited to display what I meant. 2 backslashes instead of 1. StackOverflow used the first one as escape character, so you were only seeing 1.

Comment: Oh, Makes alot more sense now